# Importing a Sketch Image into Xcode (Using UIBarButtonItem)

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, sketch-3

I am trying to put a Sketch image into a UIBarBuuttonItem. The image has a transparent background and the image is a camera that is blue with a white circle inside. *I am sure I'm exporting the entire image.* I am using a 1x, 2x, and 3x version of the image and when I set the image of a UIBarButtonItem in the storyboard, it only shows the blue part of the camera and not the white circle inside. If I put a UIImage in a ViewController and set it to the same image, the image shows up correctly. The image shows the difference. Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK0cQ.png)

Comment: The white part of your icon needs to be transparent, not white. The icon is only a mask.

Comment: Thanks! Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your image in xcasset, try change it's render to `Original image` in attribute inspector, maybe the issue is the tint color

[image]

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not seeing that option

Comment: you can see the image to see